# My game won’t save on the N64 and I tried using both save functions

Tags: nintendo-64, zelda-majoras-mask

(This is before the stone tower btw).

This started two days ago, I beat the stone tower and saved (using both the Song of Time, and saving at the Owl Statue), then the next day I went back to the game and it was just as I didn’t do it in the first place! I tried again last night several time and it still didn’t work. I deleted some of my progress on the other games on the N64. Then I tried again and it still didn’t work. What should I do? Is there a way to fix this? If so how?

When I was trying again I was doing the sound test in the bar and after I got the Mask I saved then reset the game using both save functions

Comment: Can you elaborate on a couple of things - 1. what console are you using? an original N64 only has one save function. Your mention of "both save functions" doesn't match up. 2. Can you elaborate on how you believe you are losing progress? Do you lose your masks and unique tools (Like the Bow for example)?

Comment: I was using the Nintendo 64 consul and what I meant by both save functions I meant playing the song of Time and saving at the owl   statues Ibeat the Stone tower Temple and save when I went back on it whent to the save before I even went inside the temple. When I was testing testing how I can save and not lose progress I was getting the Circus Leader’s Mask then saving and it wouldn’t save

Comment: I lost the Arrow of Light and the Giant’s Mask and the boss’s remains

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you need an accessory to assist with this. Being that the console and game are so old, it's likely that the memory is/has deteriorated, causing issues when you save your game.

While it doesn't appear to be an [SRAM game](https://www.reddit.com/r/n64/comments/8ymv2f/psa_some_of_your_nintendo_64_save_game_files_may/), that *need* a battery replacement, [others have suggested a memory expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_64_accessories#Expansion_Pak_(NUS-007)) for better performance of games such as Majora's Mask.

Comment: I have the memory expansion pack

Comment: The game does not play without the memory expansion pak.

Comment: I hav it already in the Nintendo 64

Comment: I had it in there the whole time

Comment: There is a confusing aspect to N64 Memory
1. The Expansion PAK is 4MB of RAM that is installed in the console itself and has nothing to do with saving.
2. The Controller PAK is 32 KB of Save Memory that is inserted into the controller. This save PAK does have and requires a battery to save game data. 
The batteries last 10+ years so many of them are failing. If it's 3rd party you might be able to change the battery using a screw driver. 
If it's Nintendo branded it will require a special "screw driver" and soldering in a new battery.

Comment: I don’t have memory expansion pal for the controllers though

Comment: And the controllers work fine.